# Reading from Clipboard on Chrome Extension returns "pending" Promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, promise, clipboard

I'm trying to read from the clipboard on my Chrome extension. I'm using the `navigator.clipboard.readText()` method from the ClipboardAPI to do so (because `document.execCommand('paste')` is deprecated). However, not only does the method fail to ask for user permission to read from clipboard (as done on regular web apps), but all it returns is a "pending" promise that does not get fulfilled nor rejected.

Here's the code block I'm running on a function. Neither the `clipboardString` variable nor `err` variable gets logged on the console. And the method itself returns a promise that remains "pending" forever.

```
    navigator.clipboard
      .readText()
      .then((clipboardString) => {
        console.log('Clipboard Contains: ', clipboardString);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Clipboard Error: ', err);
      });
```

Any solutions to this problem? Either what's happening with this pending promise or how to read from clipboard on a Chrome extension? Thank you.

Comment: 1) navigator.clipboard.readText will work only inside a user-initiated code like a click event. 2) Just because execCommand is deprecated doesn't mean it can't be used if there is no alternative and there is none indeed in case you want to read the clipboard outside of the user gesture. 3) Add `clipboardRead` permission to manifest.json.