# Alternatives to using deprecated document.execCommand('copy') from chrome extension popup?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use `navigator.clipboard` from an extension popup, and it returns a promise that [remains pending forever (no answers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69247963/reading-from-clipboard-on-chrome-extension-returns-pending-promise).

I've tried to do this in a content script instead, but that requires the page's document to have focus, which not even the snippet below accomplishes. And even if it could get it to work, I'd rather not have focus flicker away from the popup just because of copying to to the clipboard.

So given this, do I have any alternative than to use the deprecated `document.execCommand('copy')` from my chrome extension popup, and if I do, will this give me problems when later submitting the extension to the Chrome Web Store?

*Snippet that fails to focus document reliably*:

```
    chrome.windows.update(
        tab.windowId,
        { focused: true },
        () => {
            chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { 'active': true }, (tab) => {
                console.log("not even this is focused reliably");
            });
        },
    )
```

Comment: You can keep using execCommand, it'll work for like at least a decade.

Comment: Is there even an alternative?